# SUMing Dynamically Created Columns in MySQL

Tags: mysql

**UPDATE: Not sure if what I'm trying to achieve is possible but thanks for all the help - is it appropriate to request this be deleted?  I don't want the contributors to lose the upvotes I've given them for their help.**

UPDATE: Just to be clear, when I say columns are created 'dynamically' I mean without developer input so they are an unknown.  They are still properly defined columns in a standard database table - I just don't know the names of all of them.  :-D

I have a table with columns created dynamically (very rarely but I'm trying to make this as robust as possible).  I need to output the SUM of these columns, ordered by highest first but obviously also need the column names in the first row (as otherwise the data is useless).  I've retrieved the columns using the **information_schema.columns** method in to PHP and thought I'd iterate through the columns performing a SUM but if I do that, they are not ordered numerically.

This can be built in to an SP (I'm assuming it will have to be done in an SP due to complexity).   I believe I probably need to involve 'PIVOT' somewhere but that is the limit of my knowledge!

So to SUMmarise (see what I did there :-D )

I have a table definition with columns like this:

```
volunteerID INT
yearAdded DATETIME
willySize111to120 INT
willySize121to130 INT
willySize131to140 INT
willySize141to150 INT
```

I'd like to return a dataset like this in a query where I can specify the year:

```
sizeBracket             count
willySize111to120       98
willySize121to130       76
willySize131to140       54
willySize141to150       23
```

Every time I think I've figured out a way to do it, I hit another wall.

Thanks for any help or pointers!

Bob

Comment: Plz share whatever you have tried.

Comment: And provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Ankit - I don't have anything complete because I don't know how to go about it.  I've returned the columns as an array to PHP, looped through them, querying each column with a SELECT SUM(dynamicColumnName) WHERE yearAdded = 2012 and this allows me to build a table similar to my example but not in order.

Comment: Gordon - I put an example of the desired results in my original post.

Comment: Whether it is possible or not, doesn't invalidate the question.. I'd leave it and if the mods don't like it; they can deal with it.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your original table has a `1` in the correct bracket for each volunteer and a `0` in all other brackets:

```
  SELECT bracket.sizeBracket, COUNT(*) count
    FROM (
    SELECT CASE 
             WHEN willySize111to120 THEN 'willySize111to120'
             WHEN willySize121to130 THEN 'willySize121to130'
             WHEN willySize131to140 THEN 'willySize131to140'
             WHEN willySize141to150 THEN 'willySize141to150'
           END CASE sizeBracket
      FROM  ... -- < Table Name
      WHERE ... -- < Date Selection Logic
         ) bracket
GROUP BY sizeBracket
ORDER BY count DESC
```

**UPDATE**

Based on a raw data table `willySize` with columns

```
volunteerID INT
  yearAdded DATETIME
  willySize INT
```

You could run the following query

```
  SELECT 
      CONCAT(
        'willySize',
        ROUND(willySize-6,-1)+1,
        'to',
        ROUND(willySize+4,-1)
      ) sizeBracket,
      COUNT(*) count
    FROM willySize
GROUP BY sizeBracket
ORDER BY count DESC
```

Comment: Hi Arth, thanks for your help - this solution assumes I know the columnnames which is the really the crux of the problem.

Comment: @MrFett No problem, "I have a table definition with columns like this:" suggested a proper table.. What's your raw data table? You probably don't need the dynamic columns.

Comment: Hi Arth, There's A LOT more to this than I'm showing as it's a relatively complex database but with MASSES of data - I simplified it here.  It is a proper table, it's just that the database columns are added dynamically without developer input so are an unknown.  I may not be using the proper terminology in 'dynamic columns'?

Comment: Then I'd suggest your data structure is inappropriate.. A table `brackets`, with dynamically added rows, would be far more appropriate; then a volunteer would just need a `bracket_id`. Or you could do a simple `JOIN` based on the actual recorded size and the `brackets`'s minimums and maximums.

If you do not have access to the data structure, then you could always do the sorting in the PHP.

Comment: Arth - yep I'd compeltely agree with you based on what is here but in reality it's just appropriate - I've resorted to using PHPs array sorting to achieve what I need.  I'll probably revisit this all once I have a working prototype though.  Thanks for your help though - much appreciated!

Comment: Cool, thanks. If you could provide a more comprehensive example of your data structure and what it is trying to achieve I'd happily take a look! No worries, sorry I couldn't give you exactly what you wanted.